# Commutator of annihilation operator and momentum operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

I’m just getting to grips with annihilation and creation operators and was confused by this result:

$$[a, a^{\dagger}-a] = 1 $$

Trying to work it out I guess:

$$aa^{\dagger} - a^2 - a^{\dagger}a + a^2
= aa^{\dagger} - a^{\dagger}a
= 1 $$

Does this give

$$\sqrt{n+1}\cdot \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}
= n+1-n
= 1$$

If yes, I’m not sure why. I would greatly appreciate any tips here.

Comment: I forgot to add in the body of the question, I’m looking at [a,p], which I then write as i*sqrt(mhw/2)*[a, a†-a]

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. What exaclty do you want cleared up?

Comment: The commutator of two operators is another operator, so it cannot “give” $(n+1)-n$.  When you expand the commutator and *act on a state* $\vert n\rangle$ then you can verify for yourself if the result is still $\vert n\rangle.$

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the confusion but I would try to stress the relations which I think may things clear:
$$a|n\rangle=\sqrt{n}|n\rangle$$ $$a^{\dagger}|n\rangle=\sqrt{n+1}|n\rangle$$ So  $[a,a^{\dagger}]|n\rangle$
$$(aa†−a2−a†a+a2=aa†−a†a)|n\rangle=\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}|n\rangle-\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n}|n\rangle $$
$$\implies[a,a^{\dagger}]|n\rangle=1|n\rangle$$
Now one should note that $[a,a^{\dagger}]$ is an operator which acts on the vectors $|n\rangle$ of the hilbert space(these operators can be hermitian or non-hermitian). So when one acts $[a,a^{\dagger}]$ acts on an arbitrary vector of the hilbert space one obtains identity operator times $|n\rangle$, so $[a,a^{\dagger}]=\identity$ holds as an operator equation on the hilbert space of vectors.